# right way for accessing global variable inside if statement of javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show the alert message only once using this simple method.In this code, I want to call alert message using **end** function and reset the variable alerted using **start** function so that alert messege can be displayed after the call of start function.

But here it keep on executing alert line as much time we call the function end. Which i need to be called once until i call start function.

```
 var alerted =false;

    function start(alerted){
        if(alerted == true) {
            window.alerted=false;

    }

    function end(alerted){

        if (alerted != true) {
    window.alert("you touched the boundary please try again!!!!");
        window.alerted=true;}
    }
```

Comment: remove the parameter `alerted` from end function and check `if(!window.alerted)` {alert('something')}

Comment: now it is not alerting even single time

Comment: do the same for `start` function and wherever you are using `alerted`

Comment: yes it worked now Thank you!!!

Comment: you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to explicitly set globals onto the window and call them the same way, to make it clear that I know i'm polluting scope.

```
window.alerted = false;
const start = () => {
  if (window.alerted === true) {
    window.alerted = false;
  }
}
const end = () => {
  if (window.alerted === false) {
    alert('msg');
    window.alerted = true;
  }
}
```